# Double attributes in search url in Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have strange error in Yii2 basic template. I just generated gridview with Gii. When I try to filtr results, Url looks like that:
 `index.php?EmployeeSearch[name]=Adam&EmployeeSearch[name]=&r=employee%2Findex`

MySql table (employee) is:

- id | int(11) | autoincrement
- user_id | int(11)
- name | varchar(64)

index.php with GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'value' => function($model){ return Html::a($model->name,['employee/update','id'=>$model->id],['class'=>'a-block']); },
            'format' => 'raw'
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{delete}', 'contentOptions' =>['class'=>'text-center'], 'headerOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 60px'], 'buttons' => [ 'calendar' => function($url, $model) { return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>',$url); }  ]],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I don't know why `EmployeeSearch[name]` appears twice. The problem is with each GridView and with each filtered column.

Comment: Show your index `view` page 'GridView' definition.

Comment: Please attatch _search form in your question.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, I just pasted index.php

Answer (score 0):

In search form, **action attribute** should be added.
Otherwise will add on every search.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'action' => ['index'],  <-----------
            'method' => 'get',
]);
```